# Responsive Slider in iframe, make iframe responsive too?

Tags: html, iframe, responsive-design, resize, slider

I have a responsive slider located at - http://mymstoday.org/slider/

I HAVE to put this slider in an iframe and include it on my website.

Here is my code.

```
<iframe src="http://mymstoday.org/slider/" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" style="width:845px;height:400px;max-width:100%;overflow:hidden;border:none;padding:0;margin:0 auto;display:block;" ></iframe>
<br>
<center>test</center>
```

Problem is when I resize my window, the iframe still says at 400px at all times so I have this huge gab below it and my content.

How do I make the iframe responsive so when my slider gets smaller, so does my iframe and my content is right below it?

I tried using thise code but it is still not my desired outcome.

Please help.

```
<style type="text/css">
.videoWrapper {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
padding-top: 25px;
height: 0; }

.videoWrapper iframe {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%; }
</style>

<div class="videoWrapper">
<iframe src="http://mymstoday.org/slider/" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" ></iframe>
</div>
<br>
test
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to videoWrapper css:

```
overflow: auto;
```

and set a 0 frameborder:

```
<iframe src="http://mymstoday.org/slider/" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Sorry, this does the exact same thing for me, are you saying to do this?

Comment: <style type="text/css">
    .videoWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: auto;}

    .videoWrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; }
    </style>

    <div class="videoWrapper">
    <iframe src="http://mymstoday.org/slider/" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
    <br>
    test